# how to add extra field into the drupal xml sitemap

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, xml-sitemap

any one help me about this issue. Actually xmlsitemap module used into my drupal project. But I want to add another extra field into the sitemap xml file. Just like description.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [xmlsitemap.api.php](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/xmlsitemap/tree/xmlsitemap.api.php?h=7.x-2.x) for xmlsitemap hooks that you can use.